# Operator precedence while type casting in C

Tags: c, operator-precedence

The following piece of code gives the correct result for the multiplication

```
int var0 = 245895;
int var1 = 478565

long long val = 0;

val = (long long) var0 * var1;
```

but this piece gives the incorrect result:

```
int var0 = 245895;
int var1 = 478565
long long val = 0;

val = (long long) (var0 * var1);
```

Could anybody help me with why?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
(long long) var0 * var1
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       1
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
           2
```

In the above code, first `var0` casts to `long long`, after that, the result of multiplication will be calculated as `long long` with no overflow. In fact compiler promotes the type of `var1` from `int` to `long long` implicitly.

```
(long long) (var0 * var1)
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                  1
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
           2
```

In the second code, first multiplication occurs and the result doesn't fit in a `long` type, so the cast after that doesn’t help anymore. It casts the number that is overflow-ed before.

Therefore, the first one is better than second one to avoid overflows.

Answer (score 2):

It's all a matter of how the mid calculation result is stored:

`val = (long long) (var0 * var1);`  is interpreted as:

```
int midResult = (int)var0 * (int)var1;
val = (long long)midResult;
```

While, `val = (long long) var0 * var1` is interpreted as:

```
long long midResult = (long long) var0 * (long long)var1;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first, you are casting `var0` to `long long` then multiply it with `var1`, in the second you multiply the two variables, then cast the result to `long long`. The latter is more prone to integer overflow, because of the smaller bit count.

And regarding precendence: *multiplication* has the precedence of **3**, while *parentheses* have the precedence of **1** - the highest possible. For the complete list of operator precedence, please take a look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).